# What is the Weyl-Minkowski theorem?

Tags: polytopes, discrete-geometry

From the introductory chapter of Itamar Pitowsky's [Quantum Probability — Quantum Logic](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0021186):

> Under the second description, a vector is an element of the polytope if and only if its coordinates satisfy a set of linear inequalities which represent the supporting hyperplanes of the polytope. The existence of such a dual descripton for every polytope is known as the Weyl-Minkowski theorem.

What exactly is Weyl-Minkowski theorem? I looked online but could not understand much as it has something to do with duality in linear programming which I have only a vague idea about.

Comment: Essentially, a point in a polytope $\{x\in\mathbb R^m : Ax\leqslant b\}$ can be written as a convex combination of the vertices (extreme points) of the polytope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Math1000 [wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335176/what-is-the-weyl-minkowski-theorem#comment2713377_1335176), basically there are two ways to define a polytope: by its faces or by its vertices. [Weyl-Minkowski theorem](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/polyfaq/node14.html) says these two descriptions always exist (i.e., are equivalent).

Comment: In your link, they call it Minkowski-Weyl