# Unbounded convex hull is possible?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-hulls

I'm reading this lecture note for additional study.(https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6300/fall2008/Lectures/lec05.pdf)

*For Q the convex hull of a finite number of vectors v1, v2, . . . , vk, Q is a polytope.*
An unbounded polyhedra is not a polytope

Think of unbounded polyhedra.

The convex hull should be also unbounded? (Since the polyhedra is also a convex?)

Or in this case does it means that the convex hull doesn't exists?

Comment: That is true. If $A$ is any unbounded set and $B\supseteq A$, then $B$ is unbounded. The convex hull of $A$ always has $A$ as its subset, so the convex hull of any unbounded set is unbounded. You might contrast this with the other fact that the convex hull of any bounded set is always bounded.

Comment: I don't think your question is complete. "The convex hull [of what?] should also be unbounded?"... The convex hull of a polyhedron will be the polyhedron, regardless of whether it's bounded or unbounded... Or possibly the answer to your question is that, if an unbounded polyhedron is written as the convex hull of a set $X$, then $X$ must be infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume everything is finite dimensional. Looking at the lecture note, your question is probably related to the Weyl-Minkowski theorem for the representation of a polyhedron. Namely, if the polyhedron is closed and bounded, then it is the convex hull of its extreme points. If the polyhedron is unbounded, then it is the Minkowski sum of the convex hull of its extreme points and conic hull of its extreme rays. See this [What is Weyl-Minkowski theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335176/what-is-weyl-minkowski-theorem)