# Is it possible to express any norm balls into a polyhedron $\{x | Ax \leq b, Bx = g\}$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $\mathcal{B}(x, r) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \|x\| \leq r, r \geq 0\}$ be a ball associated with an arbitrary norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Is it possible to express any ball as a polyhedron

$$\mathcal{P} = \{x | Ax \leq b, Bx = g\}?$$

I cannot see an obvious way when I substituting in the definition of the norm, so I guess this is not possible. is this correct?

Comment: The [Minkowski-Weyl theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335176/what-is-the-weyl-minkowski-theorem) shows that such a ball would have to be the convex hull of a finite set of points. The Euclidean norm, for example, has infinitely many extreme points, which cannot be expressed as a convex combination of other points. So, no, the Euclidean ball is not polyhedral.

Comment: How about $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: Any conical combination of $l_1$ and $l_{\infty}$ norms.